# DRV8313 Brushless DC motor controller output voltage to motor is zero

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, driver, controller

I have installed two DRV8313PWP in a custom PCB and I have followed the schematic in the datasheet to control BLDC motors. After researching how to program them, i have concluded that pins EN1, EN2 and EN3 need to be at a logical 1 value, which is written in code and i have checked with a tester. In order to change the position of the motor, pins IN1, IN2 and IN3 need to be connected to a PWM signal and by comparing to a trapezoidal wave, the voltage in each of the 3 pins of the motor needs to be commuted correctly to get the desired position. However, when perhaps i tell the IN pins to be for example (255,150,50) respectively, the voltage in the OUT1, OUT2 and OUT3 pins is always zero no matter what i put through those pins. I have checked everything with a tester, and the driver is correctly powered to 12V. Maybe I'm missing something. The schematic of the connections is attached below.

[image]

Comment: nReset?  No connections?

Comment: And nSleep?  These both are active high and they both disable output and it appears they are not connected.  Never a good idea to let inputs float.

Comment: According to the [DRV8313 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8313.pdf), pin V3P3 must be bypassed by a 0.47µF ceramic capacitor.  I suggest reading every detail of the datasheet - the answer is in there.

Comment: can leaving those pins unconnected cancel the outputs? i saw that other people using them left them unconnected, and so i did not connect them. Maybe that's it

Comment: Yes, nSleep, Reset, and also shorting A/B sense to ground is important. Ref: Rpi python DRV8833 motor driver setting up and troubleshooting DC motor driving problem
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/125089/rpi-python-drv8833-motor-driver-setting-up-and-troubleshooting-dc-motor-driving.